# A abstract/general proof for the dimension formula

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

In my book of linear algebra, I am given the theorem:

Suppose V is a finite dimensional vector space and let W and U be the subspaces of V, then: dim(W + U) = dim(W) + dim(U) - dim(W $\bigcap$ U).

I didn't find a proof for this theorem in my book. How can I prove this, or how to start with it?

Comment: Can you express $W+U$ as a quotient?

Comment: Not given. Just V is a finite dimensional vector space and W and U subspaces. Further more, you also know that - if W and U are the subspaces of V - then W+U is even a subspace of V

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, we give $W\times U$ a linear space structure:
$$(w,u)+\alpha(w',u') :=(w+\alpha w',u+u').$$
This is called the direct product of two vector spaces $W\oplus U$. A simple problem is to contruct a basis of this space using bases of $W$ and $U$ proving that $\dim W\oplus U=\dim W+\dim U$.

Then we can consider a map:

$$L\colon W\times U\to V,~~L(w,u)=w-u.$$
This map is linear as:
$$L((w,u)+\alpha(w',u'))=w+\alpha w'-u-\alpha u'=L(w,u)+\alpha L(w',u').$$

We quickly calculate its kernel and image:

Kernel: $L(w,u)=0$ iff $w=u$, that is $w\in W\cap U$, so $\ker L=W\cap U$.

Image: $\text{im } L =U+W$

Then using rank-nullity theorem:
$$\dim W+\dim U=\dim W+U-\dim W\cap U.$$